# מַלְאַךְ ה׳—“the angel of GOD” or “an angel”

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, hebrew, grammar-dikduk

In various places the Torah refers to מַלְאַךְ ה׳; *e.g.*, twice in [Bereishis 22](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0122.htm).  Mechon Mamre’s JPS translation renders this as “the angel of the LORD”, but is the definite article implicit in this form of the word מלאך, or should it be translated as “*an* angel of the LORD”?

Comment: I'm not much on explaining translations but where the text reads "vayomer melech ____" (sdom, mitzrayim etc) the translations read "and THE king of _____ said". Is the lack of the explicit definite article here the same issue?

Comment: @Danno, English grammar requires the article in your example, but the meaning is unambiguous without it—there’s (usually) only one king of an area. But there are many angels; does “מַלְאַךְ ה׳” refer to a specific one?  Do Bereishis 22:11 & 22:15 refer to the same angel?

Comment: there was only one king of sdom, or there was only one king during that interaction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Status_constructus):

> In Semitic languages, nouns are placed in the construct state when they are semantically definite and modified by another noun in a genitive construction.

… which is not the way I think of it, and I'm not sure it's a *good* way of thinking of it, but maybe. Anyway, let me explain:

A noun phrase in Hebrew sometimes consists of a construct noun and another noun following. The construct noun is something like "מַלְאַךְ" and the noun following it can be "ה׳". In that case, the first, construct noun is definite, i.e. it means "the [something] of", here "the messenger of" or "the angel of". (There are [exceptions](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Gesenius%27_Hebrew_Grammar/130).)

Note, though, that the definiteness can mean various things. In particular, it need not mean that the messenger/angel under consideration is God's only messenger/angel. (This is like in English, where we say "give him the green folder": there's certainly more than one green folder, but only one under consideration at the moment.) In Genesis 22, the first "מַלְאַךְ ה׳" can't easily be read as referring to a specific messenger/angel mentioned earlier in the text, so the definiteness must be weaker, perhaps something like "the specific messenger/angel that God sent this time". Perhaps some of the commentators there discuss this, but that wasn't your question.

[More information from Gesenius.](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Gesenius%27_Hebrew_Grammar/128)

Comment: This matches what I learned in a couple different biblical-Hebrew texts, though off hand I don't recall which ones.

Comment: Is there also an indefinite version of the construct state?

Comment: @J.C.Salomon, no, a construct noun is always a definite noun.

Comment: Let me rephrase that: what would it look like if the noun were indefinite? Is there such a form at all, or could this only be expressed in a longer phrase (“an angel from among the angels of GOD”)?

Comment: @J.C.Salomon, there is no such form I'm aware of.

Answer (score 1):

Jouon-Muraoka's *A Grammar of Biblical Hebrew* (section 139) write:

> A genetive group is determinate or indeterminate according to whether the *nomen rectus* is determinate or indeterminate.

That is, the definite/indefinite quality of the construct state depends entirely on the following word (the one in absolute state). This is also how I learned it in a biblical Hebrew grammar class at Hebrew U.

For example:

סוּס הַמֶּלֶךְ - **the** horse of **the** king

סוּס מֶלֶךְ - **a** horse of **a** king -- **a** king's horse (where no particular horse is intended)

For example, Isaiah 34:8 has "שְׁנַת שָׁלוֹם", where JPS translates "a year of recompense".

There are several exceptions, see Jouon-Muraoka. For example, whether the second noun is semantically determined or not (even though it's grammatically determined) is sometimes complicated. For example: חלקת השדה (Sam 2:23:11) = "a portion of the countryside" = "a field" (השדה meaning the fields); עם נקודות הכסף (Song 1:11) = "with dots of silver" (הכסף meaning general silver); איש בנימין (Sam 1:4:12) = "a man of Binyamin". However, the general rule is for determination to follow the determination of the second word.

In particular, since ה׳ is definite, מַלְאַךְ ה׳ would (normally) be "the angel of Hashem". However, Jouon-Muraoka count this case (Gen 22) as a probable exception (presumably from context), meaning "an angel of Hashem". They note that the Septuagint translates this as "an angel of the Lord". They also note that in Judges 6, although for the *narrator* מלאך ה׳ surely means "the angel of Hashem", "for Gideon, who only later discovered the identity of his interlocutor, he must have been perceived as 'an angel of the Lord'".

Evidence for these kinds of exceptions are רוח אלהים רעה (Sam 1:16:16) and איש אלהים קדוש (Kings 2:4:9), where the undetermined adjective modifies the necessarily undetermined noun

A Google search gives more sources ([this](http://depts.washington.edu/bibheb/files/Construct.pdf) and [this](http://books.google.com/books?id=Fe1iAAAAMAAJ&lpg=PA58&ots=lKAeZvtO6L&pg=PA59#v=onepage&q&f=false)) that support the basic rule.

---

I can't account for [Wikipedia's account](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Status_constructus) of the construct being always semantically definite, but for [Gesenius](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Gesenius%27_Hebrew_Grammar/128), as quoted [another answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/30148/4940), I think many of the examples where I would say indefinite and Gesenius writes "the" are more a function of how we write things in English.  For example, he writes "the terror of a king", where I would understand that as meaning "any terror of a king", hence indefinite.

See also his point 2(e), where he writes כְּסִיל אָדָם (a fool of a man), or in 2(a) (the second one -- on the page marking on the left, it's right before page 418), where we have אִישׁ דְּבָרִים (a man of words) and אִישׁ לָשׁוֹן (a slanderer).  There's also the very common example of תַּלְמִיד חָכָם (lit. a student of a wise man).